# Making side effects explicit even in non-pure functions

Tags: go, pure-function, golang

I try to have as many pure functions as possible, but if I can't, I at least try to make the side effects as explicit as possible.

Here is an example (in Go)

```
type State struct {
    count int
}

func (s *State) IncreaseCount() *State {
    s.count += 1
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := new(State)
    s = s.IncreaseCount()
}
```

Since `s` is a pointer, `s.IncreaseCount()` would be sufficient.
I find `s = s.IncreaseCount()` makes it more obvious that `s` has changed.

But is this a good practise? Or it just makes the code more complicated than it could be?

As a side note, removing the pointer would actually make `IncreaseCount` a pure function:

```
func (s State) IncreaseCount() State {
    s.count += 1
    return s
}
```

but imagine `State` is a big complicated struct and we cannot afford copying it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A statement like

```
   s = s.IncreaseCount()
```

can have the opposite effect of what you are trying to accomplish: it can give the reader the impression `IncreaseCount` does not mutate s by itself and instead returns a new object exactly *because of this*. Hence the assignment looks like it would be required. This makes the next dev (or yourself in 6 months) think

```
  s2 = s.IncreaseCount()
```

leaves s unchanged.

Instead

```
  s.IncreaseCount()
```

is much clearer to me for two reasons:

- the name of the method is quite clear
- since there is no return value, the method must have some side effect, otherwise it would be superfluous

See also my former answer here to the question [Is modifying an object passed by reference a bad practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/370479)

Comment: Oh, boy, +1 for this answer. The first thing I imagined after reading this question was debugging why `s` changed when I thought that `s2` was the only thing that changed. Nothing can burn out a programmer faster than rooting out gremlins like that.